# Recovery files fails Raspberry Pi 3b

Tags: linux, forensics, image, raspberry-pi, recovery

i am trying to learn something about computer security, I decided to start from the linux world, through raspberry p3 with raspbian jessie OS
I would like to start with forensics file management, and I did a test on data recovery
I took an empty FAT usb stick, copied 5 images (jpg and png) and deleted 4 of 'em
I inserted the usb in raspeberry which reads it to me as dev/sda1 (the mount is on media/usb0)
from dd I made 2 images of the stick, one .raw and one .img and I copied them to the desktop, then I tried to recover data both from dev/sda1 and from the images in a Desktop/recover folder with the Foremost and Scalpel commands but I didn't get the result I expected. Here are the details:

Foremost: I have tried several commands including

```
sudo foremost -v -o /path/to/recover -i path/to/image
```

sometimes in the recover folder it created an audit.txt file and then another file with a text file icon but in reality it is a folder, inside which once there were .jpg files but they could not be opened in any way (which I know)
another time it recovered the file (1 out of 5) which I had not deleted and 1 .png which I had deleted.
in short, every time it gives me a different result.

Scalpel:
i tried the commands

```
sudo scalpel  /path/to/image -o path/to/recover
```

no result, when I launch it only the writing appears

*Scalpel version 1.60
Written by Golden G. Richard III, based on foremost o.69.*

it seems to doesn't work at all, print only a info about the version

can anyone tell me where I am wrong and can help me correct the error?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at your syntax for scalpel and swapped the order?

Comment: yes, I did it in many ways, I've tried almost 10 different attempts, following several different tutorials found on web, also for foremost, but ain't noway to do it. any alternatives?